# ViewModel is not recreated after full destroy of the Fragment (Jetpack Navigation + Dagger 2)

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-jetpack-navigation

I have the following situation: there's a bottom navigation in the app's activity. Each tab of the navigation contains it's own graph. It looks in the following way:

```
  A --- C
  |     |
\  /   \  /
 \/     \/
  B      D
```

A and C in this case - roots of the graphs, B and D - nested screens.

The problem is that when I switch to tab C, then navigate to screen D, than go back to A and go back to D again (as backstack is kept), I cannot go back to C as I am redirected back to D. I discovered, why does it happen. When I redirect from C to D at the first time, I add value to LiveData and then handle it:

```
class MasFragment {

    @Inject
    internal lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MasViewModel> { viewModelFactory }

    override fun onCreate(state: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(state)
        viewModel.apply {
            observe(navigation, ::handleRoute)
        }
    }

    private fun handleRoute(route: Route?) {
        when (route) {
            is Route.ProfileEdit.LoanHistory -> findNavController().navigate(
                MasFragmentDirections.actionMasToLoanhistory()
            )
        }
    }
}

class MasViewModel @Inject constructor() : BaseViewModel() {

    private val _navigation = MutableLiveData<Route>()
    internal val navigation: LiveData<Route> = _navigation

    internal fun openLoanHistoryInfo() = run {
        _navigation.value = Route.ProfileEdit.LoanHistory
    }
}
```

So, when I navigate from D to C after tab switching `onCreate` for `MasFragment` is called, but viewModel contains old values in liveData (as it is the same object which was after first opening of C). so redirect happens in onCreate without emitting new event. I cannot understand, why viewModel is not recreated and here I need some help. Here's my graph:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityBuilderModule::class,
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun build(@BindsInstance application: Application): AppComponent
    }
}

@Module(
    includes = [
        ViewModelModule::class
    ]
)
abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [PrivateAreaModule::class])
    internal abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity

}

@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

}

@Module(includes = [PAEditModule::class])
abstract class PrivateAreaModule {
    @PrivateAreaScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MasModule::class])
    internal abstract fun bindMasFragment(): MasFragment
}

@Module
abstract class MasModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(value = MasViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun bindMasViewModel(viewModel: MasViewModel): ViewModel

}

class ViewModelFactory
@Inject
constructor(
    private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val viewModelProvider = viewModels[modelClass]
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class $modelClass")
        return viewModelProvider.get() as T
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help